# MongoDB, array, subelement,Count,Percentage

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and learning to write mongodb queries. I need help for below problem:

Input data is a collection student having five records:

```
[
    {
        "_id":0,
        "name":"ANCY",
        "results":[
            {
                "subject":"maths",
                "score":1.46
            },
            {
                "subject":"english",
                "score":11.78
            },
            {
                "subject":"history",
                "score":6.67
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id":1,
        "name":"Nancy",
        "results":[
            {
                "subject":"maths",
                "score":60.06
            },
            {
                "subject":"english",
                "score":52.79
            },
            {
                "subject":"history",
                "score":71.76
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id":2,
        "name":"Peter",
        "results":[
            {
                "subject":"maths",
                "score":27.03
            },
            {
                "subject":"english",
                "score":6.30
            },
            {
                "subject":"history",
                "score":20.18
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id":3,
        "name":"Harry",
        "results":[
            {
                "subject":"maths",
                "score":71.64
            },
            {
                "subject":"english",
                "score":24.80
            },
            {
                "subject":"history",
                "score":1.69
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id":4,
        "name":"Paxy",
        "results":[
            {
                "subject":"maths",
                "score":28.68
            },
            {
                "subject":"english",
                "score":90.29
            },
            {
                "subject":"history",
                "score":34.41
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to get the

1) Find number of students who failed in all the three subjects (maths+ english + history)

2) Find the number of students who failed in any of the three (maths + english + history)

where the passing score is 37.
Please help me on this.

Comment: what is your expected output from above collection?

Comment: Expected answer : 1) Number of students failed in all three  subjects - Count : 2, id:0 name - Ancy ,id:1 name -Peter   2 ques) Number of students failed in any three  subjects Count : 4 , id:0 Name- Ancy ,id:2,Name : Peter,id:3 Name: Harry ,id:4 Name :Paxy.